# Scala - try-catch inside for loop with yield

Tags: scala, for-loop, try-catch, yield

I'm writing a Scala app using some 3rd party library. When iterating over a collection from that library an exception occurs, which I want to ignore, and go on with the iteration. The whole thing is inside a for loop with yield.

```
val myFuntionalSequence = for {
  mailing <- mailingCollection
} yield (mailing.getName, mailing.getSubject)
```

As said, the error occurs inside the iteration, so this line:

```
mailing <- mailingCollection
```

If I would put a try catch around the whole loop, then I cannot continue with the iteration. I have a non-functional solution to have the same output as above, but I want to keep the whole app in a functional style. This is what I came up within a non-functional way:

```
case class MyElement(name: String, subject: String)

...

var myNonFunctionalList = scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer[MyElement]()

while(mailingIterator.hasNext) {
  try {
    val mailing = mailingIterator.next()
    myNonFunctionalList += MyElement(mailing.getName, mailing.getSubject)
  } catch {
    case e: Exception => println("Error")
  }
}
```

My question is, do you know a functional way of trying to iterate through a for loop and on error skipping that element and only returning the elements where the iteration worked?

Thanks,
Felix

Comment: What is mailingCollection? If it's just a collection, then error can't be thrown in that line (unless it's your own collection, which throws an error on `map`. Maybe `getName` or `getSubject` are throwing exception instead?

Comment: Hey Krzysztof, the mailingCollection is an object from from a class of that external library. So I think the actual error is in their implementation of the iteration. But I just want to skip that error.

Comment: Is `mailingCollection` big? Do you need to process it lazily, or you can load it into list? Can you share type of `mailingCollection`?

Comment: I am not sure how you can "skip" an iteration. I mean, I would imagine that if you get an exception from the iterator, you cannot then call `.next` again and now get an element, no? Maybe by "continue with the iteration" you just mean, handle the error without throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE: I updated the answer to correct my misunderstanding of the question, as Tim pointed out in his comment.**

As mentioned in my comment, I will assume that by "continue with the iteration" you mean just not to throw the exception and still return the results up until that point. I will also assume that **you want to maintain the laziness of the `Iterator`**.

If so, I would effectively decorate the `java.util.Iterator` to protect against their bug, but returning a Scala `Iterator` so that you still have the laziness that the original library should you need it. Something (non-prod-ready) on the line of:

```
def scalaIterator[A](it: java.util.Iterator[A]): Iterator[Option[A]] = new Iterator[Option[A]](){
  private var hasBoomed: Boolean = false
  override def hasNext = !hasBoomed && it.hasNext

  override def next() = {
    Try(it.next()) match {
      case Failure(_) =>
        hasBoomed = true
        None
      case Success(value) => Some(value)
    }
  }
}
```

Now, assuming you library call return `Mailing` instances, you should wrap it in `Option`:

```
val myFuntionalSequence: Iterator[Option[(String, String)]] = for{
  mailingOpt <- scalaIterator(thirdPartyIterator)
} yield mailingOpt.map(mailing => (mailing.name, mailing.subject))
```

That will return a `Iterator[Option[(String, Int)]]`.

Example results could be (when materialized):

```
Some(mailing1Pair),Some(mailing2Pair),None // in case of an exception
Some(mailing1Pair),Some(mailing2Pair),Some(mailing3Pair) // no exception
```

Now, what if you actually don't care about that final `None`? And what if all you actually want is a `List[(String, Int)]` that contains all the successfully returned `Mailing`s? In that case, you would do:

```
val flattened: Iterator[(String, String)] = myFuntionalSequence.flatten
```

Now comes the *really* functional part ;)

But what if you actually want to know whether there was an exception? That is, you want to return `None` if there was at least one exception, or a Some(List(someMailing1Pair, etc....)) otherwise. Basically, what you want is a way to transform `List[Option[(String, String)]]` into an `Option[List[(String, String)]]`.

Enter [`Traverse`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html#traverse), from the Cats library:

```
implicit cats.implicits._
val myFuntionalSeuence: Iterator[Option[(String, String)]] = ...
val flipped: Option[List[(String, String)]] = myFuntionalSeuence.toList.sequence //notice the .toList here: we are materializing a lazy collection here
```

...at which point you treat it as any other `Option`. This approach is generic, it works with anything that implements `Traverse` and I recommend that you would read the docs I linked: you will find plenty of goodies! :)

Comment: That first expression will not return a `List`, it will return an `Option`.

Comment: yes, I realised I was assuming that the iteration was already in a separate line. Will fix the answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remain functional then you need a recursive function to unpick the unreliable iterator.

This is untested code, but it might look like this:

```
def safeIterate[T](i: Iterator[T]): List[Try[T]] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(res: List[Try[T]]): List[Try[T]] =
    if (i.hasNext) {
      loop(Try(i.next) +: res)
    } else {
      res.reverse
    }

  loop(Nil)
}
```

You can check each `Try` value to see which iterations succeeded or failed. It you just want the success values then you can call `.flatMap(_.toOption)` on the `List`. Or use this version of `safeIterate`:

```
def safeIterate[T](i: Iterator[T]): List[T] = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(res: List[T]): List[T] =
    if (i.hasNext) {
      Try(i.next) match {
        case Success(t) => loop(t +: res)
        case _ => loop(res)
      }
    } else {
      res.reverse
    }

  loop(Nil)
}
```

Someone smarter than me can probably make this return another `Iterator` rather than a `List`.